# Python, If statements with payroll program

Tags: python

Hey guys I have to do this payroll program for my programming class, but I'm about to fry my brain, because I can't get to do some if statements with the conditions my assignment is asking for. Here's what I have to do

> > Salespeople at SoftwarePirates get paid a base salary of $2000 per month. Beyond the base salary, each salesperson earns commission on
> >     the following scale:
> >
> > Sales | Commission Rate | Bonus
> >      <10000 | 0% | 0
> >
> > 10000 – $100,000 | 2% | 0
> >
> > $100,001 - $500,00 | 15% | $1000
> >
> > $500,001 - $1,000,000 | 28% | $5000
> >
> > $1,000,000 | 35% | $100,000
> >
> > The following additional conditions apply:
> >
> > 1. If a salesperson has taken more than 3 vacation days in a month, their pay gets reduced by $200
> > 2. A salesperson earns a bonus only if they have been with the company for 3 months or more
> > 3. For salespeople who have been with the company for more than 5 years and who have made sales greater than $100,000 an additional
> >        bonus of $1000 is added

Here's the code I've had so far(it's pretty messy, but I can only use if statements, not while loop or stuff like that since we are following the class book)

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
time = int(input("Enter the amount of months you've been working for SoftwarePirates Inc.: "))
vacation = input('Have you taken more than 3 days of vacations(yes or no) ')
sales = float(input("What were your sales this year? "))

def comissionOne():
    base = 24000
    print("Your commision rate is 0%, so your salary for the year is $", base)
    if time <=3:
        print("No bonus earned")
    if vacation == 'yes':
        print ("Your salary is reduced by $200 for taking more than 3 days off, leaving you at $", (base-200))
    elif vacation == 'no':
        print()

def comissionTwo():
    base = 24000
    print("Your commision rate is 2%, so your salary for the year is $", (base*0.02 + base))
    if time <=3:
        print("No bonus earned")
    if vacation == 'yes':
        print ("Your salary is reduced by $200 for taking more than 3 days off, leaving you at $", (base*0.02 + (base-200)))
    elif vacation == 'no':
        print()

def comissionThree():
    print("Your commision rate is 15%, so your salary for the year is $", (base*0.15 + base))
    if time <=3:
        print("No bonus earned")
    elif time > 3 and < 60:
        print("Bonus of $1000 earned")
    elif time >= 60:
        print("Bonus of $1000 for being in the company for over 5 years")
    if vacation =='yes':
        print ("Your salary is reduced by $200 for taking more than 3 days off, leaving you at $", (base*0.15 + (base-200)))
    elif vacation == 'no':
        print()

def main():

    print("Hi", name)

    if sales < 10000:
        comissionOne()
    elif sales >=10000 and sales <=100000:
        comissionTwo()
    elif sales >=100001 and sales <=500000:
        comissionThree()
    elif sales >=500001 and sales <=1000000:
        print("Your commision rate is 28%, so your salary for the year is $", (base*0.28 + base))
    elif sales >=1000001:    
        print("Your commision rate is 35%, so your salary for the year is $", (base*0.35 + base))



main()
```

Thank you, hope anyone can guide me through this! I just don't know how to apply the conditions to the final gross pay.

Comment: Specifically, which conditions dont work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: This condition: `elif time > 3 and < 60:` should be `elif time > 3 and time < 60:`. Also this `(base*0.15 + base)` wont work, as base is not defined in `comissionThree` nor it is a global variable.

Comment: or `elif 3 < time < 60`.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing your `if` conditions with multiple checks wrong. When you need to check multiple conditions, you are doing this:

```
if foo > 0 and < 60:
  # then...
```

But you should be doing:

```
if foo > 0 and foo < 60:
   # then..
```

or like this:

```
if 0 < foo < 60:
    # then...
```

Comment: The thing is that, I don't know how to make the base increase or decrease by each condition. For example, if I meet all the conditions I don't know how to make the base have subtractions and bonuses at the same time, I don't know how to make the variable change as it goes through each if statement